# How to generate ER diagram for specific tables in MSDB

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssms

I would like to generate ER diagram for tables in MSDB database, but in my SSMS (v18.6) I don't see **Database Diagrams** folder which is common for other databases. Is it something related to the database permissions or I have to use some other tool that can do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you create a database diagram connecting fields between various tables you are creating constraints i.e. foreign keys.

You should create new FKs only on databases you know well, not for system databases because this can block some sql feature. This is probably the reason behind the missing database diagram for system databases.

Comment: It might be, but the main purpose of the ER diagram is to see and visualize the foreign keys and not to create them.

Comment: I am curious to know this as well. My intent, not as the previous comment implied, is not to modify the relationships, but to view and understand the *existing* relationships and keys. I am not sure why there is a perceived harm there.

Comment: Use a database reverse engineering tool to obtain a database entity relationship diagram.